# Quokka.js not found in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, quokka.js

I'm trying to install Quokka.js in vscode, but when I search for it, nothing appears.
I went to the vscode web page of the extension and copied :

> ext install WallabyJs.quokka-vscode

But the extension doesn't appear : https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdD5C.png

Note that my OS is Manjaro KDE 5.23.

Is any one happend to have an idea ?

Thank you!

Comment: If I just type in "Quokka" and it shows up for me, so it might be your OS

Comment: That's what I'm thinking about, because I have it on both my windows machines, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

TLDR; You most likely have the **following**

`Code - OSS`

`VSCodium`

**RE**: https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Visual_Studio_Code

The following versions are not official ([Code - Vscode](https://code.visualstudio.com/)). make sure to install `Visual studio code`

```
peru -S code 
peru -S code-git
```

Or just use **pacman/any package manager** of choice

Comment: VSCode is official, Microsoft develops it (note the repo of Code - Oss is in https://github.com/microsoft/vscode), it's just the branded release for Windows and MacOS

Comment: @Samathingamajig +1 thanks for pointing that out. i made a big mistake